# ImportError: No module named pygame, how do you fix this on a mac?

Tags: python, pygame, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to create a game in python, just a beginner, and I installed pygame using the pip command `pip install pygame` and it says "requirement already satisfied". So, assuming it is installed, I hop onto VS Code, and the `import pygame` to check if it is working, and the `ImportError: No module named pygame` error popped up in the terminal, keep in mind I am on a MacBook. Please help.[Here is the image of what the error is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP2uR.png)

Comment: First check  in vscode  that you are using correct python interpreter where you installed module

Comment: like the answer below says, install a python `venv`, activate the `venv`..then install your package in that `venv`..use `which python` command to make sure you are using the venv interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to use `pip3` on MacOS, `pip` is for Python 2.

Try this:

`pip3 install pygame`

and then run the command:

`python3 -c "import pygame"`

If the second works, but in VSCode it doesn't, remember to use Python 3, instead of 2 for VSCode.

Comment: I have the exact same problem but the second line doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

You shoud try `pip3` instead `pip` because I remembered that osx already have a version of python2.7(which deprecated). And remember to call CLI

```
python3 game.py
```

But I prefer using virtual environment ( [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) )than install every packages in your user profile.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on Mac and fixed it by following these steps:

1. In terminal, install `pygame` properly by using this command:

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

2. Test it using below command to see if it's successfully installed:

```
python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens
```

3. The reason the VSCode cannot find the `pygame` model is because the Python interpreter path is not correct by default, and you have to change it to your Python path:
4. Search your Python path by using below command in terminal:

```
whereis python
```

[image: Command]

5. Then copy the path and paste it in the setting of interpreter path of Python in VSCode as shown here:

[image: VSCode settings]

Re-run the `.py` file and it should be working.